# Calculate highest maximum 3 values in hash

Tags: ruby

I have a class which will take user request as json
shown below:

```
   json = { "val": { "a": 10, "b": 50, "c": 20, "d": 30, "e": 15 } 
   }
```

and return max 3 of hash value:

for eg:

It should return:

```
{
"b": 50
"d": 30
"c": 20
}
```

This is my approach:

```
require 'json'

module UserRequest
  class << self
    def call(json)
      original = JSON.parse(json)
      covers   = original["covers"]
      calculate_max(covers, 3)
    end

    def calculate_max(covers, max_num)
      sorted = covers.sort_by { |k, v| v }
      Hash[max_array(sorted, max_num)]
    end

    def max_array(array, max_num)
      size = array.size
      array.slice(size-max_num..last)
    end
  end
end

UserRequest.call(json)
```

Is there any better way to do this. Please help. Should follow SOLID ruby principles

Comment: It's not very SOLID if this thing takes in JSON, parses it, and then does a bunch of other magical things, all because you called `call`. Try and break that down a bit more. Consider using `extend self` at the end in preference to stuffing everything inside `class << self`, or even using `def self.call` instead. Also prefer `array.to_h` in preference to the old-style `Hash[array]`.

Comment: Hint: [`max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) can give you the top three if you tell it what "top" means.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with json? You have a hash held by a variable `json` and wish to derive another hash from it.

Answer (score 5):

This should work

```
  module UserRequest
    class << self
      def call(json:, key: 'val', limit: 3)
        json[key].max_by(limit){|_,v| v}.to_h
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: @user6500179 Thanks for the help. Also, I need how would I make my class definition better so that it follows SOLID principles in ruby

Comment: @maxmitch I would put that in one class method and have optional arguments if that makes sense for your use case. See edited answer

Comment: `max_by(limit, &:last)` for a slightly more obscure approach. :)

Answer (score 1):

Other option, given the input json:

```
json = "{\"val1\":{\"a\":10,\"b\":50,\"c\":20,\"d\":30,\"e\":15}, \"val2\":{\"z\":100,\"x\":50,\"w\":200,\"y\":30,\"v\":150}}"
```

You could sort on the fly while parsing to Hash, this applies to any key:

```
require 'json'
h = JSON.parse(json).transform_values { |v| v.sort_by { |_, v| -v } }
```

So you can define some methods in your class or module:

```
h['val1'].first(3).to_h #=> {"b"=>50, "d"=>30, "c"=>20}
h['val2'].last(3).to_h #=> {"z"=>100, "x"=>50, "y"=>30}
```

Or use `to_json` instead of `to_h`.